C# FTP conection to filezilla with disable plain unencrypted ftp
I am trying to change the way my application is connected to a filezilla server after some changed from a security point of view.
at first it was just added the enable FTP over SSL/TLS and this one is now working
the next step will be to enable the "Disallow plain unencrypted ftp", but when this flag is checked, my application gets a message of unauthorized access.

here is my code
FtpWebResponse response = null;
        try
        {
            // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
            FtpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(completePath) as FtpWebRequest;
            request.CachePolicy = new System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy(System.Net.Cache.RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
            request.Proxy = null;
            if (request == null)
            {
                result.SetError(Translate.InvalidUrl, completePath);
                return false;
            }
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

            request.Credentials = NetworkCredential;

            response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            responseStream = new MemoryStream();
            response.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(responseStream);
            responseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        }

How can I modify my code in order to be able to connected to the FTP server with this configuration?
Thanks
Andrea
